# How do I use the setPriority() method correctly?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here's a question on a test that I got wrong, I'm confused by how setPriority(Thread.MIN_Priority) and setPriority(1) differ.

Q:  Assume your multithreaded program has a background thread (called batchThread) which does some lengthy processing, what would be the proper way of setting its priority to allow the rest of the system to be very responsive while batchThread is running?

a) batchThead.setPriority(1);

b) batchThead.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

c) batchThead.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

d) batchThead.setPriority(Thread.MID_PRIORITY);

I chose C and got it wrong.  Appreciate the help as always.

Comment: this is hard to believe.

Comment: I know!  I thought I was right!  I'm going to email my instructor right away.

Comment: It is worth nothing that setPriority is just a hint depending on the OS and whether you are root/administrator or not. It is generally not worth playing with as the OS can determine whether a thread is IO bound or CPU bound and take action accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe they're one in the same. According to the Java docs, Thread.MIN_PRIORITY is 1: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Thread.MAX_PRIORITY

Perhaps your instructor was mistaken?

Comment: probably, I think this test was made by some corporate goombas in India who have no idea what they're doing. This was part of a pre-test that was given to us from our company before starting a java course.